Center div in screen but use container to hide overflow
I want to make a header for an mobile app with Quasar/Vue.
The header should have 3 divs in a row. The first one has a Toggle-Button, the second one is the actual title and the last div contains a smaller Button.
The challenge now is to center the title of the whole screen (first and last div is not the same width), but also it shouldn't go over/below the outer divs:
TITLE
------------------------ 
|D---1|    TITLE         |D2| 
------------------------ 

VERY LONG TITLE
------------------------
|D---1|VERY LONG...|D2| 
------------------------ 

OR

VERY LONG TITLE
------------------------ 
|D---1|...Y LONG TI...|D2|  
------------------------ 
I am also open to further suggestions.
I already tried a lot of combinations.
